# Search in solr with multivalued location field

Tags: solr, lucene, geolocation

I can index multiple values for location type field in solr. The response for a modified `schema.xml` and indexing modified exampledocs looks like
the query:

```
  http://192.168.3.19:8983/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=*:*
```

The response:

```
{
    "id":"TWINX2048-3200PRO",
    "name":"CORSAIR  XMS 2GB (2 x 1GB) 184-Pin DDR SDRAM Unbuffered DDR 400 (PC 3200) Dual Channel Kit System Memory - Retail",
    "manu":"Corsair Microsystems Inc.",
    "price":185.0,
    "popularity":5,
    "inStock":true,
    "manufacturedate_dt":"2006-02-13T15:26:37Z",
    "payloads":"electronics|6.0 memory|3.0",
    "cat":["electronics","memory"],
    "store":["37.7752,-122.4232","37.7752,-122.4232","38.7752,-122.4232","39.7752,-122.4232"],
    "features":[
      "CAS latency 2,\t2-3-3-6 timing, 2.75v, unbuffered, heat-spreader"]},
  {
    "id":"VS1GB400C3",
    "name":"CORSAIR ValueSelect 1GB 184-Pin DDR SDRAM Unbuffered DDR 400 (PC 3200) System Memory - Retail",
    "manu":"Corsair Microsystems Inc.",
    "price":74.99,
    "popularity":7,
    "inStock":true,
    "manufacturedate_dt":"2006-02-13T15:26:37Z",
    "payloads":"electronics|4.0 memory|2.0",
    "cat":["electronics","memory"],
    "store":["37.7752,-100.0232","37.7752,-122.4232","38.7752,-122.4232","39.7752,-122.4232"]},
  {
    "id":"VDBDB1A16",
    "name":"A-DATA V-Series 1GB 184-Pin DDR SDRAM Unbuffered DDR 400 (PC 3200) System Memory - OEM",
    "manu":"A-DATA Technology Inc.",
    "popularity":0,
    "inStock":true,
    "manufacturedate_dt":"2006-02-13T15:26:37Z",
    "payloads":"electronics|0.9 memory|0.1",
    "cat":["electronics","memory"],
    "store":["45.17614,-93.87341","37.7752,-122.4232","38.7752,-122.4232","39.7752,-122.4232"],
    "features":[
      "CAS latency 3,\t 2.7v"]},
  {
```

witch means the data are stored correctly.
If I query for the first stored geolocation it works fine, but if I search for third or fourth geolocation solr returns no result.
If I run the following query:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=*:*&fq={!geofilt%20pt=45.17614,-93.87341%20sfield=store%20d=5}
```

I get the right answer:

```
{
        "id":"VDBDB1A16",
        "name":"A-DATA V-Series 1GB 184-Pin DDR SDRAM Unbuffered DDR 400 (PC 3200) System Memory - OEM",
        "manu":"A-DATA Technology Inc.",
        "popularity":0,
        "inStock":true,
        "manufacturedate_dt":"2006-02-13T15:26:37Z",
        "payloads":"electronics|0.9 memory|0.1",
        "cat":["electronics","memory"],
        "store":["45.17614,-93.87341","37.7752,-122.4232","38.7752,-122.4232","39.7752,-122.4232"],
        "features":[
          "CAS latency 3,\t 2.7v"]},
      {

But if the query is:

    http://localhost:8983/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true&q=*:*&fq={!geofilt%20pt=38.7752,-122.4232%20sfield=store%20d=50}
```

I will get no results.
Is this a solr issue? Any solution?

Comment: Can you show us the query that you are using where no results are being returned.

Comment: I updated the question, sorry for delay, but it was weekend ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old question, but it's still in many Google search results, so here's more information for multi-valued coordinate fields:

You can add the following to your schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="location_rpt" class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
           spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
           distErrPct="0.025"
           maxDistErr="0.000009"
           units="degrees" />
```

Then use the `location_rpt` field for a multi-valued coordinate field, and benefit from all the advantages [Solr 4's new spatial search](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search#SpatialSearch-SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType(abbreviatedasRPT)) offers.

You will also need to add the [JTS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jts-topo-suite/) jar to your solr class path if you use the custom spatialContextFactory. If you remove that parameter from the `fieldType` definition, multi-value fields still work, but other advanced features won't.

Answer (score 2):

According to the ticket (SOLR-2154) refered by vuky in d whelan's answer this should be in all  new Solr releases. This was fixed by ticket SOLR-3304 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3304), which was marked as fixed at September 17, 2012.

I can't really find a specific release from which it should work, but I suppose everything released after May 2013 should work if I read the comments in the tickets.

Answer (score 0):

LatLon types can't be multiValued.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#LatLonType

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer, but it's more complicated, more details and hopes for solution on: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2154